Why a variable in a parent scope is "out of scope" of a child one
I got a problem understanding the scope with rust. I try to implement a simple code to play a sound. I want to fill a buffer then play it, but I can't get it compiling.
I got this method:
fn main() {
    let channels: usize = 2;
    let device = initialize_device();
    let config = initialize_configuration(&device, channels as u16);

    let mut stream_buffer = [0.0 as f32; 64];
    {
        let mut oscillator = Oscillator::new(440.0 as f32, 0.0 as f32, 44100.0 as f32, &mut stream_buffer);

        let processor = move |_data: &mut [f32], _: &cpal::OutputCallbackInfo| {
            //FIXME: Send data from oscillator to _data
            oscillator.process();
        };
    
        let stream = build_outputstream(config, device, Box::new(processor));

        let _ = stream.play();

        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(2000));
    }
}

The variable "stream_buffer" is just before a scope
    let mut stream_buffer = [0.0 as f32; 64];
    {
        ...
    }


where the rest of the code is executed.
From what I understand from documentation of rust is that by default, variables are on the stack and we can box them to have them on the heap.
So, stream_buffer is on the stack and should stay on the stack until the end of the program. Even if I don't manually create the scope below it.
According to the doc also, the variables on the heap are destroyed automatically when they go out of scope.
So, I understand that the lifecycle of my boxed processor is shorter that the stream_buffer and it's destroyed at the end of its scope.
 let mut stream_buffer = [0.0 as f32; 64];
    {
        let mut oscillator = Oscillator::new(440.0 as f32, 0.0 as f32, 44100.0 as f32, &mut stream_buffer);

        let processor = move |_data: &mut [f32], _: &cpal::OutputCallbackInfo| {
            //FIXME: Send data from oscillator to _data
            oscillator.process();
        };
    
        let stream = build_outputstream(config, device, Box::new(processor));
        ...
    }

But the compiler complains that "stream_buffer" does not live enough...
error[E0597]: `stream_buffer` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:42:88
   |
40 |     let mut stream_buffer = [0.0 as f32; 64];
   |         ----------------- binding `stream_buffer` declared here
41 |     {
42 |         let mut oscillator = Oscillator::new(440.0 as f32, 0.0 as f32, 44100.0 as f32, &mut stream_buffer);
   |                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
49 |         let stream = build_outputstream(config, device, Box::new(processor));
   |                                                         ------------------- cast requires that `stream_buffer` is borrowed for `'static`
...
55 | }
   | - `stream_buffer` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: due to object lifetime defaults, `Box<dyn for<'a, 'b> FnMut(&'a mut [f32], &'b OutputCallbackInfo) + Send>` actually means `Box<(dyn for<'a, 'b> FnMut(&'a mut [f32], &'b OutputCallbackInfo) + Send + 'static)>`

If I put the stream_buffer as static as the compiler suggest, it works. But I don't want to.
I think I understand that because processor must be on the heap, I have no choice but make the stream_buffer static? Can't I have the stream_buffer on the stack and the processor on the heap?

hint: The boxed processor is moved into build_outputstream, meaning that your scope no longer owns it and is not responsible for dropping it.

Ok, thank you.
But the build_outputstream is in the same scope ?
So, the stream_buffer is still alive when stream is destructed ?

Hello Eggyal,
I'm sorry, I really don't understand how it works.
Even if borrow checking can't see inside function, the function call is in the scope. So, it's also bounded to this scope no ? I pass the boxed variable to function, so it "create" another scope for the function. But when the function is finished, the scope of the function ends and boxed variable should be destroyed, no ?

Here is a minimal example of your problem:
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello world");
    let clo = || {println!("{s}");};
    takes_boxed_fn(Box::new(clo));
    
}

fn takes_boxed_fn(_: Box<dyn Fn()>) {}

and the error it produces:
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:3:30
  |
3 |     let clo = || {println!("{s}");};
  |               --             ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
  |               |
  |               value captured here
4 |     takes_boxed_fn(Box::new(clo));
  |                         ------------- cast requires that `s` is borrowed for `'static`
5 |     
6 | }
  | - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: due to object lifetime defaults, `Box<dyn Fn()>` actually means `Box<(dyn Fn() + 'static)>`

has a great note that explains the problem:
= note: due to object lifetime defaults, `Box<dyn Fn()>` actually means `Box<(dyn Fn() + 'static)>`

that means the definition of takes_boxed_fn is equivalent to this:
fn takes_boxed_fn(_: Box<dyn Fn() + 'static>) {}

which requires your closure to be static! Fortunately that is relatively easy to relax, just pass an explicit lifetime:
fn takes_boxed_fn<'a>(_: Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>) {}

Playground

Hello, great, thank you. :)
I understood your solution to correct my code, but I still don't understand why the box as a static lifetime by default :/
Documentation states (if I well understood) that a a boxed variable is created on the heap and that it's lifetime is bounded to its scope. So, why should I have to specify the lifetime ?
Thank again.

The Box isn't the problem, the trait object inside it is, and a Box doesn't have a lifetime associated with it that the trait objects lifetime could be derived from.
